# Beautiful Soup distinguish text with or without tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
html1=
...
<span class="ruby"><span class="rb">textrb1 </span><span class="rt">textrt1 </span></span>text1 <span class="ruby"><span class="rb">textrb2 </span><span class="rt">textrt2 </span></span>text2
...
```

In the end, I want to print something like: `textrb1 (textrt1) text1 textrb2 (textrt2) text2`, text in the bracket.
If I print `html1.text`, I get all the text without bracket: `textrb1 textrt1 text1 textrb2 textrt2 text2`
I can access to textrb1 by `html1.find('span',class='rt')`.
I want to know how to access to the 'normal' text text1 and text2 in the right order like

```py
for text in volltext:
  if text is textrt:
    texts.append('('+text+')')
  else:
    texts.append(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find_parent(class_="rt")` on `NavigableString`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<span class="ruby"><span class="rb">textrb1 </span><span class="rt">textrt1 </span></span>text1 <span class="ruby"><span class="rb">textrb2 </span><span class="rt">textrt2 </span></span>text2
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

out = []
for text in soup.find_all(text=True):
    if text.strip() == "":
        continue
    if text.find_parent(class_="rt"):
        out.append("({})".format(text.strip()))
    else:
        out.append(text.strip())

print(" ".join(out))
```

Prints:

```
textrb1 (textrt1) text1 textrb2 (textrt2) text2
```